# VBscript automate click on OK on Popup button

Tags: vbscript, automation

I have Web form and when I fill in fields with Vb-script i get popup message box OK/Cancel. 
I can not get my script to click on that OK button. Anyone has solution?

```
Set IE = Createobject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
IE.Navigate "*******/page"
IE.Visible = True
Wscript.Sleep 500
IE.Document.All.Item("user").Value = "username"
IE.Document.All.Item("pass").Value = "password"
IE.Document.All.Item("submit").Click ' ******here popup window appears
Wscript.Sleep 500
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" ' ******this does not execute
```

Comment: Have you tried WshShell.SendKeys "%o" Instead?

Comment: It executes SendKeys method out of IE. It cant see Popup Messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I wrote a second script with the soul purpose of sending "ENTER" after a delay of 1 second (or whatever) and execute this file right before you "Click" Submit.
it's a very ugly workaround, but it works. so it'll have to do until I find a better selution